# imshow only one colour channel with openCV from RGB image and looping through all pixels in one colour channel

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to split the RGB .jpg image into three channels:

```
imread = cv2.imread("picture.jpg")

blue = imread[:, :, 0]
green = imread[:, :, 1]
red = imread[:, :, 2]

cv2.imshow("preview", blue)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but the code will display grayscale image. The same is with the green and red arguments passed to the imshow function.

Is it possible to preview it only as a blue channel image?

Also, how would I loop through all the pixels of one channel, let's say: the blue one?

#

Try `imread[:, :, 1] = 0` that makes the blue pixel value to 0. In the same way you can modify the pixels. But while reading the image i am not sure either. But if you want to go through over each pixel then probably the best way is going through looping.

```
def slow():
     img = imrerad.copy()
     height, width, depth = img.shape
     for i in range(0, height):  
         for j in range(0, width):  
             for k in range(0,depth): 
                 img[i,j,k] = 0  # The value you want to modify with
     return img


def fast():
     img = imread.copy()
     height, width, depth = img.shape
     img[0:height, 0:width, 0:depth] = 0  # The value you want to modify with if every value is same..
     return img
```

or if you have anything better regarding your algorithm then we can look for a better solution. Depending on your need. That first one is very slow where as the second one is a quite faster than the previous one.

#

I cannot answer this question from my account but somehow i thought this would help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to split opencv image to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118398/unable-to-split-opencv-image-to-rgb)

Comment: @beaker, agreed. Haven't seen it. Do you possibly know how to iterate over each pixel in one channel image?

Comment: Why do you want to loop through all pixel of a channel ?

Comment: I am trying some algorithm, so I need to loop each pixel of a single channel and get it's value.

Comment: @Amaterastis Can you provide the algorithm in the question? There may be more efficient ways than looping through each pixel.

Comment: Can you post the "comment" in your question as an answer? The way its integrated into your question right now is quite confusing.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54183300/2836621

Comment: That's how Vamish posted it and I've accepted his proposal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell. thanks for the link! :)

Comment: So you would use `cv2.imshow("Blue",  cv2.merge([b,zeros,zeros]))` to show the blue channel in blue